# Solving an equation mod $n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Part of a solution, I'm trying to calculate $(n-1)^2$ in $mod\ n$ when $n\in\mathbb{N}$. What I tried to do:

$$ (n-1)^2=(n^2-2n+1)\ (mod\ n)$$

But I'm not sure what to do next. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 3):

$n-1\equiv -1 \pmod n$

So $(n-1)^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1\pmod n$.

....

Or $n^2= n*n \equiv 0 \pmod n$.  And $-2n\equiv (-2)*n\equiv 0 \pmod n$.  ANd  $1 \equiv 1\pmod n$.

So $n^2 - 2n + 1 \equiv 0 + 0 + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

...

You just need to keep is mind for $a\equiv \alpha \pmod n$ and $b \equiv \beta \pmod n$

That $a \pm b\equiv \alpha \pm \beta \pmod n$ and $ab \equiv \alpha \beta \pmod n$ and $ma\equiv m\alpha \pmod n$  and $a^k \equiv \alpha^k \pmod n$ and that $n \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

*EVERYTHING* falls from that exceedingly nicely.

(In other words *nearly* all arithmetic distributes over modulus, and that $n$ is equivalent to $0$.)

(So $(n-1)^2$ is over modulus then, under $\mod n$ arithmetic, the same thing as $(-1)^2$.)

(A few things to watch out for.  Division doesn't distribute unless divisor and modulus are relatively prime.  And the powers of exponents are not actually arithmetic so they don't distribute.)

Answer (score 0):

Since $${n^2}\equiv 0\pmod n$$ $$-2n\equiv 0\pmod n$$
You have $${(n-1)^2}\equiv ({n^2}-2n+1)\equiv 0+0+1\equiv1 \pmod n$$